# How to get values of key in AngularFire 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm having problems with getting values of a unique key using AngularFire in Angular 2.

This is my structure:

[image]

As you can see, the reports has unique keys witch values inside it. I can easily get those values using `*ngFor` but what I wanted is to get values of a unique key. This is my code:

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  item: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { 
    this.item = af.database.list('/reports/-Ka2fkQJ3krtBztMtiRD')
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**html:**

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-title>Report</md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    {{item.plateNumber}}
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

As you can see, I want to get values inside the key `-Ka2fkQJ3krtBztMtiRD` so what I did is `af.database.list('/reports/-Ka2fkQJ3krtBztMtiRD')`. I get nothing and not even an error.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You if you want an observable that refers to a single object, rather than a list, you should use [`FirebaseObjectObservable`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md):

```ts
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
...
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { 
    this.item = af.database.object('/reports/-Ka2fkQJ3krtBztMtiRD');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And your template would be something like this:

```html
<md-card>
  <md-card-title>Report</md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    {{(item | async)?.plateNumber}}
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

If you are concerned about having lots of `item | async` expressions sprinkled throughout your template, you can take advantage of [`ngIf`'s support for local variables](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13297#issue-194251997):

```html
<md-card *ngIf="item | async; let i">
  <md-card-title>Report</md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    {{i.plateNumber}}
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```